# Node, child processes

Tags: node.js, child-process

thus i have been reading every thing in the Node Docs and googled a lot... its still not clear to me how to use child processs...in the best way...
(My code is running on windows)

Do i need to use exec or fork?

I like to be able to spilt up my code... so instead of running a single loop with 300 (i = 1 to 300) iterations... i would like to run 3 child processes - which executes / loop through 100 iteration each...

So i need to send some variable(s) to each child process...like a start index to use in the loop (i = 0, 100 or 200)...

How do i do this? Can some body show me a complete example?

Comment: Do you have any code that you wrote that wasn't working?

Comment: Dont confuse child process in Node. js to multiple threads in other languages.  spawning a child process is only creating a complete new Node. js process that starts with the specified module. They are completely new Node. js processes.  They cannot directly access each other's variables/functions .  You must use message passing.  Please post your code for more help.

Comment: Please show me how to send an object/array to the child from the parent - using Spawn!... in the initial (spawn)call to create the child process... why should this be so complicated?